# Change of variables into the unit ball

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Question: Express the volume of the solid bounded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded below by the surface $z = x^2 + 2y^2$, and above by the plane $z = 2x + 6y + 1$, as the integral of a suitable function over the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $0$, then calculate the volume.

Before going any further, please only give me small hints since this is a homework question.

Ok, I know that $z = x^2 + 2y^2$ is a "cylinder" where each horizontal cross-section is an ellipse. I used software to take a look at the region in question. I figure that I might be able to find a change of variables to transform the region into the unit cylinder, then from there I can go ahead and reduce it to an integral over the unit ball. I'm not sure if this is correct and I have no idea on how to proceed further.

EDIT: What if I found a diffeomorphism, say F, from the ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2$ onto the unit ball, then plugged the plane $z = 2x + 6y + 1$ into F. Then the original region would be transformed into the region bounded below by F(ellipse) and above by F(plane) right? It's quite late where I am and I have school in the morning. I will head to bed now and sleep on this problem for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Combining the two surfaces together:
$$x^2+2y^2=2x+6y+1$$

This is the projection of the intersection onto $xy$-plane. Apparently it is not the unit circle. To transform it to a unit circle, a simple change of variable would work. Before that, we need to complete the square:
$$(x-1)^2+2(y-\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{13}{2}$$

Since you are just asking for a hint, I will leave it to you to find the change of variable. After that, the integrand should be the subtraction of the two surfaces.

Comment: So $(x-1)^2 + 2(y-\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{13}{2} \implies \frac{2}{13}(x-1)^2 + \frac{4}{13}(y - \frac{3}{2})^2 = 1 \implies (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{13}}(x-1))^2 + (\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}(y-\frac{3}{2}))^2 = 1$. So then my change of variables is $g(u,v) = (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{13}}(u-1), \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}(v - \frac{3}{2})$. So my original integral was $ \int_B f$ where $B$ was the projection of the intersection onto the $xy$-plane and $f$ is the plane subtract the other surface. The change of variables theorem implies that this integral is equal to $\int_A (f \circ g)\left|det(Dg)\right|$.

Comment: @JonathanGafar: Yes, that is correct. You are welcome.

Comment: Hold on, shouldn't the function actually be the inverse of the one that I posted? The function that I posted takes $P$ onto the unit ball, but I'm looking for the function that takes the unit ball onto $P$. So it's $g^{-1}$ that I should use, right?

Comment: @JonathanGafar: Sorry yes should be $g^{-1}$. Good job discovering that.